# How to automate running Linux commands via `ssh` from Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, ssh, automation, putty

Currently I use puTTY, open SSH connection to my Ubuntu server and execute some svn update comment over there.

I want to automate that whole process but executing just a script/batch file.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it myself without using Cygwin - I'm stuck with installing/reinstalling it.

The answer is using `Plink` from `PuTTY`.

```
rem Note
rem ----
rem 01 Update `plink` to point to `plink.exe` on `your PC`
rem 02 Update `pkey` to point to `private key` of `remote server`
rem (the end)

set plink="Path\To\PuTTY\plink.exe"
set user=<your user>
set server=<remote server>
set pkey="Path\To\YourPrivateSSHKey.ppk"
set pass=<your pass>

set run=%plink% -v -pw %pass% -i %pkey% %user%@%server%

rem sample run command
set cmd=svn update /var/www/MyWeb

%run% %cmd%
rem (the end)
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Install Cygwin and use its shell and ssh client.

Comment: Please give more detail on using Cygwin and `ssh` from there. Thank you!

Comment: I know how to google... Hope that you are more eager to help us. In fact, I've tried Cygwin and failed to call `ssh`. Any idea Makholm?

Comment: As long as you refuse to be more specific about your problems than "tried and failed", then I'm not very eager to help, no.

Comment: I'll try again. Return to you later Makholm.